# Can mutt handle exclamation points instead of colons in file names?

Tags: mutt, maildir, offlineimap

I'm wanting to move my maildir folder to a different disk that has a Window file system. However, the file system does not allow colons (:) in file names, which Maildir uses in some file names by default. There is an option for Maildir to use another character in place of a colon. [Exclamation point is common](https://docs.python.org/2.5/lib/mailbox-maildir.html). However, I've read a warning that "[you will probably loose compatibility with other programs trying to read the same Maildir.](http://www.offlineimap.org/doc/offlineimap.html)" when using this option.

I only use mutt for reading this mail. Can mutt handle exclamation marks in place of a colon in filenames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the source code I'm afraid this is not possible in [mutt](https://github.com/muttmua/mutt/blob/78ab1cc/mh.c#L1447-L1468) nor [neomutt](https://github.com/neomutt/neomutt/blob/d524c9f/maildir/shared.c#L1157-L1182) at the moment. Links lead to latest commits in master branch as of now. In both cases the colon separator is hardcoded in the source code.